# Conversion of C# system type in a custom type

Tags: c#, dictionary

Its C# class library project.
Class has only one function which returns a dictionary,

```
//dictionary definition 
Dictionary<string, int> stockLengths = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    stockLengths.Add("Length_5000", 0);
    stockLengths.Add("Length_3000", 0);

//return statement
Value result = new Value(stockLengths);
    return result;
```

the system calling class library is not accepting the dictionary with following error:

" ***Use Configurator Types instead of System.Type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Int32]*** "

Here Configurator = A custom software, which is calling the class library dll...

What am i missing here, can convert a system type of dictionary into any custom type so that the host system can accept data type being returned...

```
// Value struct

 public struct Value : IEquatable<Value>
    {
        public static readonly Value Null;

        public Value(string value);
        public Value(decimal? value);
        public Value(decimal value);
        public Value(bool? value);
        public Value(bool value);
        public Value(IExpressionValue value);
        public Value(IExpressionValueCollection value);
        public Value(IExpressionValueArray value);
        public Value(DataType valueType);
        public Value(object value);

        public object Data { get; }
        public bool HasValue { get; }
        public Type ValueType { get; }
        public DataType Type { get; }

        public IExpressionValueArray AsArray();
        public bool AsBoolean();
        public IExpressionValueCollection AsCollection();
        public bool? AsNullableBoolean();
        public decimal? AsNullableNumber();
        public string AsNullableString();
        public decimal AsNumber();
        public string AsString();
        public Value Clone();
        public Value ConvertTo(DataType type);
        public bool ConvertToBoolean();
        public bool? ConvertToNullableBoolean();
        public decimal? ConvertToNullableNumber();
        public string ConvertToNullableString();
        public decimal ConvertToNumber();
        public string ConvertToString();
        public override bool Equals(object obj);
        public bool Equals(Value other);
        public override int GetHashCode();
        public string GetTraceString();
        public override string ToString();

        public static implicit operator Value(decimal? value);
        public static implicit operator Value(bool value);
        public static implicit operator Value(bool? value);
        public static implicit operator Value(decimal value);
        public static implicit operator Value(string value);
    }



public interface IExpressionValueCollection : IEnumerable<IExpressionValue>, IEnumerable
    {
        IExpressionValue this[string key] { get; }

        int Count { get; }
        IEnumerable<string> Keys { get; }

        bool Contains(string key);
        IExpressionValue GetOrCreateElement(string key, DataType valueType);
    }


public interface IExpressionValue
    {
        Value Value { get; }

        IExpressionValue GetProperty(string identifier);
        bool TryGetProperty(string identifier, out IExpressionValue property);
    }  


 public enum DataType
    {
        Unassigned = 0,
        Boolean = 1,
        String = 2,
        Number = 3,
        DateTime = 4,
        BooleanArray = 5,
        StringArray = 6,
        NumberArray = 7,
        CollectionArray = 8,
        Collection = 9,
        UnassignedArray = 10
    }
```

[image]

Comment: don't you have official document or sample code to start with?

Comment: That `Value` type just looks like `System.Linq.Expressions` with extra steps. "Use Configurator Types" clearly you have a library that can only process specific types that you will have to use. But you haven't provided any context about this library for us to answer your question.

Comment: @LeiYang YES, i have sample code but it shows only simple datatype return like string, and int... (and it works fine) but when i return Arrays or collections the host system asks to "Use Configurator Types instead of System.Type"...

Comment: @JeremyLakeman YES you are absolutely right... as i said in reply to LeiYang the basic types are returned without any hassle (int, string etc) and for Arrays or Collections/Dictionaries host system asks me to  "Use Configurator Types instead of System.Type"... i have copied all the relevant code below the statement... please specify any thing else you require ?

Comment: so what's the **ultimate** goal?

Comment: @LeiYang to convert the Dictionary in "such a form" that host system will accept it... Remember there is no issue in return and library is working fine, There is no issue when int / string return as well... but arrays and collections are some how need to be converted into some other custom type... (see the Value stuct code below the question statement (public IExpressionValueCollection AsCollection();) this needs to done...

Comment: i mean, why do you need do those at all? is the application/library name, version, a commercial secret? How do you provide a **working example** for us, with simple types of int, string as you said?

Comment: `so that the host system can accept data type being returned...` Impossible to help unless we know what data types the host system _can accept_.

Comment: @LeiYang A windows software allows to execute external code (.NET Assembly) and use the return results in its normal flow... When i use external class library to for processing some data and it returns basic int, string etc. it works but not with Arrays / Collections... I have added a picture of screen capture of the return statement lines (working and not working and where i think help is required... )

Comment: A windows software --- means nothing to us

Comment: @mjwills YES, you are right, the host software have multiple data types as also described in the code below the question "public enum DataType", i am concerned with 9th (Collection)... (remember bool, string, int/number etc. there is no issue)...

Comment: @LeiYang A window software = Infor Design Studio v. 8.1.0.66 (www.inform.com),
Sorry I though its irrelevant as the issue I am facing is how to convert a "system data type" into a custom one... YUP its a custom library but I want to learn out a generalized way of doing this so that I can apply that knowledge to solve this problem... thanks for your help on this...

Comment: this is not a generalized problem, it is very speicific. currently the only way i can think of is go to its official site and try to find some sdk documents.

Comment: @LeiYang the library will return data of type "Value"
see the check mark in the image below question, "resultString" is a simple string and its being returned and ACCEPTED by host software without any hassle...
the Value struct has 10+ overloads and my concerning is IExpressionValueCollection (see image where "I am stuck here" tag)
C# dictionary "stockLengths" is ready but when i return it the host software deny it, I need to some how convert it into of type  IExpressionValueCollection... 
May be that will help... or you require any other file please let me know...

Comment: You will need to write your own data type that implements `IExpressionValueCollection`. Or read the docs to see if they have made one for you. Then map your dictionary to that type (or, more likely, have your type use a dictionary as its internal data store).

Comment: Note when the OP says inform.com earlier, they likely instead mean infor.com . https://docs.infor.com/lsf/10.0/en-us/lsfunixolh/default.html?helpcontent=wal1546299518903.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution was not available in provided docs, when I contacted technical support they only offered a tip and then with a little bit more exploring I was able to successfully convert the system data type into "THE" data type which host software support... Here I am providing solution, to help out someone like me:

```
    using TDCI.BuyDesign.Configurator.Engine;
    using TDCI.BuyDesign.Configurator.Engine.Expressions;
    using TDCI.BuyDesign.Configurator.Engine.RuleEngine;

            // sample code to return Collections 
            var returnCollection = new SimpleExpressionValueCollection();
            returnCollection.Add("Length_5000", 5000);
            returnCollection.Add("Length_3000", 3000);

            Value result = new Value(returnCollection);
            return result;
            
            // sample code to return arrays 
            var returnArrays = new SimpleExpressionValueArray(DataType.String);
            returnArrays.Add(new SimpleExpressionValue("Test Value 1"));
            returnArrays.Add(new SimpleExpressionValue("Test Value 2"));
            returnArrays.Add(new SimpleExpressionValue("Test Value 3"));

            Value result = new Value(returnArrays);
            return result;
```